# Android developer console - delete rating

Tags: android

I recently published an app in the play store, and I have one review that contains some bad language in it (and a minimum rating). How can I delete it? I don't see any report review button...

I'm not sure if I'm in the correct site, please direct me to a better one if that's the case.

Comment: You can report a review on the play store as a normal user: useful, not useful, spam. And no, you are wrong here :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot delete anything like user comments or ratings. You may want to report the comment to Google (using contact form). But I'd not cross my fingers too much for quick reaction (if any)